# How do you fix "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str" error from nested dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am having a TypeError "Exception has occurred: TypeError tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str". I am using python 3. Here is my code below:

```
    with open('item_info.json') as item_info:
        item_data = json.load(item_info)
    
    for collection in item_data:
        print(f'\n {collection}')
        for skin in item_data[collection].items():
            if skin['rarity'] == 'Consumer Grade':
                print(skin)
```

I have a large JSON file that I have imported using the JSON library in the variable `item_data`, `collection` is a dictionary containing nested dictionaries once loaded by the JSON library and `skin` is every individual dictionary within the `collection`, holding a key named `'rarity'`. I would like to print every `skin` that has a value of `'rarity'` equal to `'Consumer Grade'`. I am trying to do this by nested for loops, as there are multiple collections and I'd like to loop through every skin in every collection as a check.

Here is a sample of the imported JSON held in `item_data`:

```
{
    "2018_inferno": {
        "MP5-SD | Dirt Drop (Factory New)": {
            "rarity": "Consumer Grade"
        },
        "MAC-10 | Calf Skin (Factory New)": {
            "rarity": "Industrial Grade"
        }
    },
    "2018_nuke": {
        "Five-SeveN | Coolant (Factory New)": {
            "rarity": "Consumer Grade"
        },
        "Negev | Bulkhead (Factory New)": {
            "rarity": "Industrial Grade"
        }
    },
    "alpha": {
        "Five-SeveN | Anodized Gunmetal (Factory New)": {
            "rarity": "Consumer Grade"
        },
        "P250 | Facets (Field-Tested)": {
            "rarity": "Industrial Grade"
        }
    }
}
```

The output should look something like this:

```
2018_inferno
{"MP5-SD | Dirt Drop (Factory New)": {"rarity": "Consumer Grade"}}

2018_nuke
{"Five-SeveN | Coolant (Factory New)": {"rarity": "Consumer Grade"}}

alpha
{"Five-SeveN | Anodized Gunmetal (Factory New)": {"rarity": "Consumer Grade"}}
```

or (more desirable)

```
2018_inferno
"MP5-SD | Dirt Drop (Factory New)"

2018_nuke
"Five-SeveN | Coolant (Factory New)"

alpha
"Five-SeveN | Anodized Gunmetal (Factory New)"
```

Comment: What are you expecting `skin` to be set to at `skin['rarity']`? It's currently a tuple, not a dictionary. Did you mean to call `.items()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`skin` is a tuple of the the key-value pairs from `item_data[collection].items()`. Tuples cannot be accessed using string indicies (`skin['rarity']`)

You can iterate both keys and values at the same time, to make it easier to iterate, for example

```
for collection, item in item_data.items():
    print(f'\n{collection}')
    for k, v in item.items():
        if v.get('rarity') == 'Consumer Grade':
            print(k)
```